# How to resolve Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 4504 (HeapTaskDaemon) in Android App

Tags: android

My current Android application intermittently crashes with:-

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 4504 (HeapTaskDaemon)
```

The entire crash is reported as follows:-

```
2021-02-03 14:34:29.355 11984-4504/com.my.application A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 4504 (HeapTaskDaemon), pid 11984 (my.application)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.359 3610-3655/? I/display: HWC setVsyncEnabled = 0
2021-02-03 14:34:29.484 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: unknown process state: t
2021-02-03 14:34:29.520 3579-3579/? E/audit: type=1701 audit(1612362869.515:1416): auid=4294967295 uid=10442 gid=10442 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c186,c257,c512,c768 pid=11984 comm=5369676E616C2043617463686572 exe="/system/bin/app_process32" sig=11
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4503: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4504: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4509: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4510: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4512: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4516: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4553: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4579: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4753: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4774: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4775: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4780: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4791: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4810: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4831: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4853: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4862: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4863: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4868: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4882: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4951: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.521 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4966: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4967: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4968: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4969: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4970: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4972: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4973: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4974: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4975: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4976: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 4977: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5087: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5088: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5094: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5095: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5102: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5103: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5104: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5105: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5106: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5108: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5464: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5672: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5673: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5674: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5676: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5677: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5678: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5679: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5680: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5681: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5682: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5683: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5685: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5686: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5720: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5721: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.522 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5722: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5723: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5724: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5741: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5742: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5743: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5745: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5748: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5781: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5785: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5790: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5791: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5798: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5799: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5800: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5801: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5802: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5803: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5805: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5806: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5807: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5808: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5809: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5812: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5814: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5815: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5816: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5817: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5818: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5819: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 5820: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? E/crash_dump32: failed to detach from thread 11984: No such process
2021-02-03 14:34:29.523 5887-5887/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
2021-02-03 14:34:29.531 3747-3747/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 4504
2021-02-03 14:34:29.534 5887-5887/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 11984 (target tid = 4504)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.552 4051-4227/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '17df825 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=573
2021-02-03 14:34:29.552 4051-4227/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '17df825 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-02-03 14:34:29.552 4051-4227/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'cfcd43b com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.home.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=584
2021-02-03 14:34:29.552 4051-4227/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'cfcd43b com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.home.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-02-03 14:34:29.554 4051-6039/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=492
2021-02-03 14:34:29.555 6311-6311/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=76
2021-02-03 14:34:29.555 4051-6001/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.my.application (pid 11984) has died: fore TOP (111,296)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.556 4051-6001/? D/ActivityManager_KPM: Killed Process Scenario:7 , App PID:11984 , App Name:com.my.application , App ADJ:0 , App AdjType:top-activity , Current CCH-ACT Count:1 , Proc State:2
2021-02-03 14:34:29.557 4051-6042/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{17df825 u0 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity}
2021-02-03 14:34:29.557 4051-6042/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '17df825 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity (server)'
2021-02-03 14:34:29.557 4051-6042/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: '17df825', fd=573
2021-02-03 14:34:29.559 3747-3747/? W//system/bin/tombstoned: crash socket received short read of length 0 (expected 12)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.562 4051-6042/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity$_11984)/@0x2c6a503 called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:1790 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:720 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeImmediately:2333 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2469 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.access$300:264 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:3040 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:685 <bottom of call stack> 
2021-02-03 14:34:29.563 3656-4758/? I/Layer: id=1204 removeFromCurrentState com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity$_11984#0 (50)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.564 3656-3734/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1204 Removed com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity$_11984#0 (50)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.567 3656-3734/? I/Layer: id=1203 removeFromCurrentState 17df825 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity#0 (50)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.569 4051-6042/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{17df825 u0 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity} to null displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:202 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked:6203 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.access$300:264 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:3040 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:685 
2021-02-03 14:34:29.570 4051-4068/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{cfcd43b u0 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.home.HomeActivity}
2021-02-03 14:34:29.570 3595-3595/? I/Zygote: Process 11984 exited due to signal 11 (Segmentation fault)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.570 4051-4068/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'cfcd43b com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.home.HomeActivity (server)'
2021-02-03 14:34:29.570 4051-4068/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'cfcd43b', fd=584
2021-02-03 14:34:29.570 3656-3734/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1203 Removed 17df825 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity#0 (50)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.574 3656-3734/? I/Layer: id=1185 removeFromCurrentState cfcd43b com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.home.HomeActivity#0 (50)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.575 3656-3656/? I/Layer: id=1203[1] Destroyed 17df825 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity#0
2021-02-03 14:34:29.575 4051-4713/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus left window (11984): 17df825 in display 0 0
2021-02-03 14:34:29.576 3656-3734/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=1185 Removed cfcd43b com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.home.HomeActivity#0 (49)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.577 3656-3656/? I/Layer: id=1204[1] Destroyed com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity$_11984#0
2021-02-03 14:34:29.579 3656-3656/? I/SurfaceFlinger: Display 0 HWC layers:
        type    |    handle    | flag |  format   |   source crop (l,t,r,b)    |         frame       | name 
    ------------+--------------+------+-----------+----------------------------+---------------------+------
         DEVICE | 0xef74c8c0 | 0000 | RGBA_8888 |   0.0    0.0 1200.0   36.0 |    0 1884 1200 1920 | StatusBar$_4399#0
         DEVICE | 0xed84f7c0 | 0000 | RGBA_8888 |   0.0    0.0 1200.0   72.0 |    0    0 1200   72 | NavigationBar0$_4399#0
2021-02-03 14:34:29.580 4051-4092/? I/WindowManager: Focus moving from Window{17df825 u0 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity} to null displayId=0
2021-02-03 14:34:29.580 4051-4092/? I/WindowManager: Losing focus: Window{17df825 u0 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity}
2021-02-03 14:34:29.581 4051-6001/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{dab286d u0 com.my.application/.ui.details.DetailsActivity t352}: app died, no saved state
2021-02-03 14:34:29.583 4051-6001/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application released (0)
2021-02-03 14:34:29.583 4051-4092/? E/WindowManager: RemoteException occurs on reporting focusChanged, w=Window{17df825 u0 com.my.application/com.my.application.ui.details.DetailsActivity}
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:575)
        at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.windowFocusChanged(IWindow.java:829)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.reportFocusChangedSerialized(WindowState.java:3691)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:5262)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

I interpret this line:-

```
2021-02-03 14:34:29.531 3747-3747/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 4504
```

as meaning the crash report is held at location `system/bin/tombstoned`

however I cannot locate `tombstoned` directory.

How can I gather sufficient information to enable me to resolve this crash and stop it occurring?

From this logcat content it appears to be related to my Apps UI somehow.
Which I find puzzling as my App employs "standard" UI views and widgets.

Comment: I had this crash today too for a couple of times, then it stopped happening. Did you figure it out by now?

Comment: I still haven't resolved this issue. It only seems to occur on Samsung devices though

Comment: `/data/tombstones`?

Comment: this seems to be problem with interaction with memory. you might be using some memory extnsive task .

Comment: although you might wanna look into this link : https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug

Comment: @Darkman i cannot locate the /data/tombstones folder. where should i be looking?

Comment: @Hector `find / -type f -iname '*tomb*' -exec printf '%s\n' {} \+ 2>/dev/null`

Comment: The problem goes away when I  did a "Invalidate cache and restart" and redeploy the app. For me, the culprit is in the "Database Inspector". Every time I use that, the problem returns.

Answer (score 2):

Apps using the **Database Inspector** may crash when running on the Android 11 emulator, with an error like the following appearing in logcat:

```
 Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
```

To fix this issue, upgrade your Android 11 emulator to version 9 or higher by navigating to **Tools > SDK Manager**. **In the SDK Platforms** tab, check the box labeled **Show Package Details and select revision 9** or higher of the Android 11 emulator.

[image]

Comment: what if this is happening on Android 11 Device, not in emulator??

Comment: Of the times I observed this behavior on the device it was sometimes that the change through the instant run failed or the times I used the app inspector (Database ) in android versions that did not support it since the app inspector only works from api 26 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was receiving this kind of crash because I had the specified kind of function directly inside Stateless widget. It caused a crash on the screen open.

```
class Abc extends StatelessWidget {
    Abc();

    final Function xyz = () async {
    ...
    }
}
```